# Почему при вставке изображения кисть рисуется в другом месте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, рисование

При вставке изображения кисть рисуется в другом месте от курсора. Как сделать так, чтобы этого не происходило?

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, QAction
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)

        self.brushColor = Qt.black
        self.brushSize = 8

        self.setGeometry(200, 300, 650, 500)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        colormenu = mainMenu.addMenu("Сюда")

        saveAction = QAction("Вставить фото", self)
        colormenu.addAction(saveAction)
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save)

    def save(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "", "",
                                               "PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*)")[0]
        if filename == '':
            return
        self.image.load(filename)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.coords = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton:
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.coords, event.pos())
            self.coords = event.pos()
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = Window()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Оффтоп, проверка `event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton` хоть и работает, но она неправильная, нужно так: `event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton`. Суть в том, что `buttons` возвращает флаг, а битовое и (`&`) проверит, что значение флага `Qt.LeftButton`. Или проверяйте на `==`: ``event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton``

Comment: Поигрался с вашим кодом и понял почему при рисовании на картинке происходит сдвиг курсора -- причина в разном размере картинки и окна. Рисуете вы ведь на картинке, а после саму картинку рисуете на окне, поэтому появляются такие отличия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поигрался с вашим кодом и понял почему при рисовании на картинке происходит сдвиг курсора – причина в разном размере картинки и окна. Рисуете вы ведь на картинке, а после саму картинку рисуете на окне, поэтому появляются такие отличия.

Можно сделать еще одну картинку, она будет прозрачная, на ней будет рисунок и ее нужно будет поверх всего рисовать. Единственное, что при изменении размера окна нужно будет ей тоже менять размер

Пример:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, QAction
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image_foreground = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.image_foreground.fill(Qt.transparent)

        self.image_background = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.image_background.fill(Qt.white)

        self.brushColor = Qt.black
        self.brushSize = 8

        self.setGeometry(200, 300, 650, 500)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        colormenu = mainMenu.addMenu("Сюда")

        saveAction = QAction("Вставить фото", self)
        colormenu.addAction(saveAction)
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save)

    def save(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "", "", "PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*)")[0]
        if not filename:
            return
        self.image_background.load(filename)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image_background, self.image_background.rect())
        painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image_foreground, self.image_foreground.rect())
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.coords = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            painter = QPainter(self.image_foreground)
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.coords, event.pos())
            self.coords = event.pos()
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = Window()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

**PS.**

Если не нужно, чтобы картинка растягивалась под размер окна, то в `drawImage` первым параметром передавать размер картинки, а не окна:

```
painter.drawImage(self.image_foreground.rect(), self.image_foreground)
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного другой подход. Для разнообразия.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen


class Menu(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drawing = False
        self.lastPoint = QPoint()
        self.image = QPixmap("im.png")
        self.resize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.image)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton and self.drawing:
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 3, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainMenu = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @r64 зачем вы удалили пост https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1204768/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4 ? Только начал думать чем вам помочь, а вы поторопились. Восстановите его.